# Issue to fetch data by condition

Tags: ydn-db

again I need help in ydn db. I have an object store where objects has these attributes:

```
id, published, tempId, sonyId
```

I set published, tempId and sonyId to the indexes :

```
keyPath : 'id',
name : 'XYStore'
indexes : [{ keyPath : ['published', 'sonyId', 'tempId'}]
```

Now my query to filter by published and sonyId does not work:

```
db
.from('XYStore')
.where('sonyId, published', '=', ['15', '1'])
.list()
.done(function(records) {
    console.log(records);
});
```

What did I made wrong? If I remove 'tempId' from indexes than everything works fine.
I add tempId to the indexes because in another fetch method I call all entries by tempId:

```
db
.from('XYStore')
.where('tempId', '=', '8')
.list()
.done(function(records) {

});
```

I am not really sure. What did I made wrong?

Thanks in advcance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to index each query as follow:

```
indexes : [{ 
  keyPath : ['published', 'sonyId']
}, {
  keyPath : 'tempId'
}],
```